# Google custom search as_sitesearch does not work

Tags: google-search

Our custom search covers all our sub domain such as wcce.aju.edu, mba.aju.edu and so on.
I am trying to create the URL query string to limit the results to only one sub domain as follows:

```
http://maed.aju.edu/zsearch.aspx?zoom_query=miriam&as_sitesearch=wcce.aju.edu
```

This does not work.

In the aspx page I have added the following

```
<input type='hidden' name='as_dt' value='i'/>
<input type="hidden" name="as_sitesearch" value="wcce.aju.edu"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<gcse:search as_sitesearch = "www.mydomain.com/site1"></gcse:search>
```